# profile update from admin site only

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a personal portfolio project. I want to add/update the profile dynamically. What I want is to have one profile image and one personal image(about_pic). I want to update them from the admin section/site. I only want to add one profile object.

`model.py`

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_pic = ImageField(upload_to='profile', blank=True, null=True)
    background_pic = ImageField(upload_to='profile', blank=True, null=True) # you can leave it for now
    about_pic = ImageField(upload_to='profile', blank=True, null=True)
```

`views.py`

```
def home_view(request, tag_slug=None):
    profile = Profile.objects.all() 
    return render(request, 'mypf/index.html', { 'profile':profile })
```

`index.htm`

```
# profile pic
{% for p in profile %}
  <img src="{% if p.profile_pic %} {{ p.profile_pic.url }} 
  {% else %} {% static 'img/natsu.jpg' %}
  {% endif %}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
{% endfor %}

# about pic
{% for p in profile %}
  <img src="{% if p.about_pic %}
    {{ p.about_pic.url }} {% else %} {% static 'img/img2.jpg' %}
    {% endif %}" width="150px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail">              
{% endfor %}
```

Also, How can I do efficiently without using two loops since there is another HTML code like div, main, section. Is there another way?

[image: image looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is a portfolio, and there will only ever be one instance of `Profile`, what you are talking about is a singleton. There are a few ways of doing this, but the best would probably be to use a third-party package, such as [`django-solo`](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo).

This will enforce there only ever being one `Profile` instance, and it will also give you a more appropriate django-admin interface for `Profile`. Rather than clicking through to a list view where you could potentially add many, you'll click on `Profile` on the admin homepage and it'll take you straight through to your only `Profile` instance.

#### How to avoid the 2 for loops

Again, there are multiple ways to do this. Rather than passing down the whole `Profile` queryset, in your home view you could just do this:

```
def home_view(request, tag_slug=None):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1) 
    return render(request, 'mypf/index.html', { 'profile':profile })
```

And then your template will look lke this:

```
# profile pic
  <img src="{% if profile.profile_pic %} {{ profile.profile_pic.url }} 
  {% else %} {% static 'img/natsu.jpg' %}
  {% endif %}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">

# about pic
  <img src="{% if profile.about_pic %}
    {{ profile.about_pic.url }} {% else %} {% static 'img/img2.jpg' %}
    {% endif %}" width="150px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
```

#### A slightly better way

Hard-coding the `id` in your view as I've done above isn't particularly nice, so if you use `django-solo` you can improve this by doing something like:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get()
```